# How to convert a text list into a PHP associative array with key=value?

Tags: php

I have a list in a text file:

```
 Alabama    
 Alaska     
 Alberta    
 ...
```

and I would like to have a PHP array like that :

```
 array('Alabama' => 'Alabama', 'Alaska' => 'Alaska', ...)
```

How could I have this array ? (I am a beginner in PHP and in computing in general).
Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, to have this array generated dynamically from a text file or is it a one-time task that you will save as PHP for later use?

Comment: identical key and value seems pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// read the file as an array of lines
$lines = file('./myFile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// fill the array
$arr = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $arr[$line] = $line;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to read the entire file to an array, and use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) to assign the array keys.

```
$arr = file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$arr = array_combine($arr, $arr);
```

Comment: Very cool idea. Thank you @flowfree! I wish I could vote your post twice :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could actually read a file into an array.

```
$states=require('path/to/states.php');
```

then in the states.php file

```
return array(
   'Alabama' => 'Alabama',
   'Alaska' => 'Alaska'
   // and so on.
);
```

You would have to format your list, but that should be pretty easy using a text editor with regex.

Comment: Does your file contain an array?